# Redirect users to different page after a login failure in d7

Tags: 7, users

I want to redirect the users to different page if they enter the wrong login details, for that I am using following code but it is not working.

```
function bartik_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
    if ($form_id == "user-login")
    {
        $form["#validate"][] = "bartik_validate_login";
    }
}

function bartik_validate_login($form, &$form_state)
{
    // on successful login, the uid is set in form_state.
    if (empty($form_state["uid"]))
    {
        $_GET["destination"] = "some url goes here";
        drupal_goto("some url goes here"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18301720/drupal-form-error-redirect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with the correct form_id for user login.

i.e: `if ($form_id == 'user_login') {`

The form_id can be found in the HTML source hidden element

`<input type="hidden" name="form_id" id="edit-user-login" value="user_login">`

Comment: it seems the problem is about why `drupal_goto` not worked on validator

Answer (score 1):

in form validation or form submit handler try to change 'redirect` to go to another url, So Try

```
$form_state['redirect'] = 'some_url';
```

and Also as @David Thomas mentioned, you are some mistakes in your form alter replace `user-login` with `user_login`, but I don't think your problem is there, **I think your main question is about how to redirect to another page on your validator function.**

Comment: the benefit in redirecting it from validation handler itself would be to avoid any submit handler to work before ours.

Comment: @arpitr yes, you right, in this case there is only logon checking and this is safe.